# Is Komamura the only shinigami who has an animal-like appearance?

Tags: bleach

Is Komamura the only shinigami who has an animal-like appearance?

Comment: Very interesting question. I never thought of that.

Comment: Yeah.. This really made me very curious.. I wonder what he was in his past life. A dog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [List of Shinigami](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Shinigami), Komamura Sajin with his wolf/dog-like appearance is the only one, although:

> Yoroichi comes close, with her cat-form, that she "prefers" to be in.

Comment: how were you able to do that?

Comment: @Cyberson If you were referring to how I added the spoiler text, well, that's done using the >! markup. For future reference, you could read the formatting help or click on 'edit' to see the markup.